# Web Components: Is there an equivalent to attributeChangedCallback for properties?

Tags: javascript, callback, web-component, object-properties

You're not supposed to put rich data (objects, arrays, functions) in HTML element attributes. Instead, it's suggested to only put rich data in properties (according to the [Google custom elements best practices article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices#aim-to-only-accept-rich-data-objects-arrays-as-properties)). I need to run actions when these properties are updated. We have `observedAttributes` and `attributeChangedCallback`, but there's nothing similar for properties.

Let's say I have a `user` prop with things like `name`, `DoB`, and `address` on it. I thought I might be able to trick `observedAttributes` by putting a bunk setter *a la*

```
set user(val) {
  return;
}
```

Didn't work. `return this.user = val` gives an infinite loop.

My only idea at this point is to have a property called `_user` that simply gets set to `[Object object]` on every change, which triggers the change I actually want. Don't really like that though.

**UPDATE**: This is what I'm currently doing

In `user-info.js`:

```
class UserInfo extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    subscribers.push({ element: this, props: ['user'] });
    this._user = state.user;
    this.render();
  }
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['user'];
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    this.render();
  }
  get user() {
    return this._user;
  }
  set user(val) {
    if (JSON.stringify(val) !== JSON.stringify(this._user)) {
      this._user = val;
      return this.setAttribute('user', val);
    }
  }
  render() {
    this.innerHTML = `<span>${this._user.name}</span> was born on <span>${this._user.dob}</span>`;
  }
}
```

In `main.js`:

```
document.querySelector('.actions--user').addEventListener('input', e => {
  state.user = {...state.user, [e.target.dataset.action]: e.target.value};
})
```

Comment: If you are using the property then why bother with the attribute. Seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to detect updated properties of an object.

```js
customElements.define( 'user-info', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this._user = {
        name: 'Bruno',
        dob: '1/1/2000'
    }
    this.render();
    this._proxy = new Proxy( this._user, {
        set: ( obj, prop, val ) => {
            if ( prop === 'name' ) 
                if ( this._user.name !== val ) {
                    console.log( 'username updated to ' + val )
                    this._user.name = val
                    this.render()
                }
        }
    } )
  }
  get user() {
    return this._proxy
  }
  set user(val) {
    if (JSON.stringify(val) !== JSON.stringify(this._user)) {
      this._user = val
      this.render()
    }
  }
  render() {
    this.innerHTML = `<span>${this._user.name}</span> was born on <span>${this._user.dob}</span>`
  }
} )
```

```html
<user-info id=ui></user-info><br>
<label>Name: <input oninput="ui.user.name=this.value"></label>
```

---

Alternately you could define a User `object / class` with setters that would interact with the custom element.

```js
class User {
  constructor( elem ) {
    this._elem = elem
    this._name = 'Bruno'
    this._dob = '1/1/2000'
  }
  set name( val ) {
    if ( val !== this._name ) {
      this._name = val
      this._elem.render()
    }
    return false
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
  get dob() {
    return this._dob
  }
  update( obj ) {
    this._name = obj.name
    this._dob = obj.dob
  }
}

class UserInfo extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this._user = new User( this )
    this.render()
  }
  get user() {
    return this._user
  }
  set user(val) {
    this._user.update( val )
    this.render()
  }
  render() {
    this.innerHTML = `<span>${this._user.name}</span> was born on <span>${this._user.dob}</span>`
  }
}

customElements.define( 'user-info', UserInfo )
```

```html
<user-info id=ui></user-info><br>
<label>Name: <input oninput="ui.user.name=this.value"></label>
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @BennyHinrichs thank you, i've added an alternate solution (without proxy)